# Computations of derivatives on traces and determinants

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus, trace

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$I am looking for some indications on how to approach the following derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bf{W}} (\tr(\bf{Y}^T(\bf{WW^T}+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}\bf{Y}))$$

and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bf{W}} \log(|\bf{WW^T} + \sigma^2I|)$$

I have been using [matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf)

For the first one, using eq.59 from the above document i believe that i have the following

\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial}{\partial \bf{W}} (\tr(\bf{Y}^T(\bf{WW^T}+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}\bf{Y})) \\[10pt]
= {} & \bf{Y^T}(\bf{WW^T}+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}\frac{\partial (\bf{WW^T}+\sigma^2 I)}{\partial \bf{W}} (\bf{WW^T}+\sigma^2 I)^{-1} \bf{Y} 
\end{align}

Set $\Sigma = \bf{WW^T}+\sigma^2 I$

And obtain $2\bf{Y^T\Sigma^{-1}W\Sigma^{-1}Y}$, implying that $\bf{W}$ is symmetric thus $\frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial W}=2\bf{W}$

For the second one, using eq.46, I obtain

$$\frac{1}{|\Sigma|}|\Sigma|\tr\left(\Sigma^{-1}\frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial \bf{W}}\right) = \tr(\Sigma^{-1}\bf{W})$$

Are these computations correct?

Comment: I do not understand why did you use equation (59). I cannot see any inverse of a matrix. The same for the second case, why do you use (46) for an expression with log?

Comment: ok, it should be $(\bf{WW^T }+\sigma^2 \bf{I})^{-1}$ but i ll leave this solution here for future use.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, define a new variable $$\eqalign{
M&=WW^T+\sigma^2I\cr
dM&= d(WW^T)\cr
&=(dW\,W^T+W\,dW^T)\cr
&=2\operatorname{sym}(dW\,W^T)\cr
}$$
Use this new variable and the Frobenius Inner Product to rewrite the first function, 
and find the differential and gradient $$\eqalign{
\tau&=Y:MY=YY^T:M\cr\cr
d\tau&=YY^T:dM=YY^T:2\operatorname{sym}(dW\,W^T)\cr
&=2\operatorname{sym}(YY^T):dW\,W^T\cr
&=2YY^TW:dW\cr\cr
\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial W}&=2YY^TW\cr
&=2YY^T(WW^T+\sigma^2I)\cr\cr
}$$
Now use the new variable in the second function $$\eqalign{
\lambda&=\log(\det(M))\cr\cr
d\lambda&=d\log(\det(M))\cr&=d\operatorname{tr}(\log(M))\cr
&=M^{-T}:dM\cr
&=M^{-T}:2\operatorname{sym}(dW\,W^T)\cr
&=2\operatorname{sym}(M^{-T}):dW\,W^T\cr
&=2M^{-T}W:dW\cr\cr
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial W}&=2M^{-T}W\cr
&=2(WW^T+\sigma^2I)^{-1}W\cr\cr
}$$

Comment: When you write {\rm tr} instead of \operatorname{tr} then you don't get proper spacing to the left and right of $\operatorname{tr}$ in things like $a\operatorname{tr}b$ and $a\operatorname{tr}(b)$. I mention both the case with $b$ in parentheses and the case without those so that you can see the context-dependence in the spacing. Similarly with \operatorname{sym}. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this, but could you please update the solution of the first term to the updated situation (the middle term has an inverse after all). Sorry for the mess